# How to rewrite qi parsers with qi::_1/qi::_N in x3?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-x3

Let's say we want to parse an inner product expression and get the result.

```
"SUM({1, 2, 3} .* {4, 5, 6})"
```

`qi::_1` and `qi::_2` are very convenient to reference the *i*th attributes in the parser.

```
void Test(std::string const& input) {
    qi::rule<decltype(boost::begin(input)), int(), qi::ascii::space_type> ruleSum =
        (
            qi::lit("SUM") >> '(' >>
            '{' >> (qi::int_ % ',') >> '}' >>
            ".*" >>
            '{' >> (qi::int_ % ',') >> '}' >>
            ')'
        )[qi::_pass=phx::bind(
            [](std::vector<int> const& vec1, std::vector<int> const& vec2, int& result) {
                if(vec1.size() != vec2.size())
                    return false;
                result = std::inner_product(boost::begin(vec1), boost::end(vec1), boost::begin(vec2), 0);
                return true;
            },
            qi::_1, qi::_2, qi::_val
        )];
    int attr = 0;
    if( qi::phrase_parse(boost::begin(input), boost::end(input), ruleSum >> qi::eoi, qi::ascii::space, attr) ) {
        std::cout<<"Match! result = "<<attr<<std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout<<"Not match!"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

In spirit x3, there are no such qi::_1 ... qi::_N. Should I use a pair of vectors as the attribute? What is the recommended way to parse something like this inner product?

```
namespace inner_product {
    x3::rule<struct idInnerProduct, int> const ruleInnerProduct("InnerProduct");
    auto const ruleInnerProduct_def =
        (
            x3::rule<struct _, std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>>>{} =
                x3::lit("SUM") >> '(' >>
                '{' >> (x3::int_ % ',') >> '}' >>
                ".*" >>
                '{' >> (x3::int_ % ',') >> '}' >>
                ')'
        )[([](auto& ctx){
            if(_attr(ctx).first.size() != _attr(ctx).second.size()) {
                _pass(ctx) = false;
            } else {
                x3::_val(ctx) = std::inner_product(
                    boost::begin(x3::_attr(ctx).first),
                    boost::end(x3::_attr(ctx).first),
                    boost::begin(x3::_attr(ctx).second),
                    0
                );
            }
        })];
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(ruleInnerProduct)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute is a fusion sequence. Its members are `vector<int>`.

A fusion sequence is not a pair, so you can't use `.first` or `.second`.

I'd write:

```
void Test(std::string const& input) {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    auto ruleSum = x3::rule<struct _, int> {} =
        (
            x3::lit("SUM") >> '(' >>
            '{' >> (x3::int_ % ',') >> '}' >> ".*" >>
            '{' >> (x3::int_ % ',') >> '}' >>
            ')'
        )[( [](auto& ctx) {
                using boost::fusion::at_c;
                // dissect context
                auto& pass = x3::_pass(ctx);
                auto& result = x3::_val(ctx);
                std::vector<int> const& vec1 = at_c<0>(x3::_attr(ctx));
                std::vector<int> const& vec2 = at_c<1>(x3::_attr(ctx));

                // do the work
                pass = (vec1.size() == vec2.size());
                if (pass)
                    result = std::inner_product(boost::begin(vec1), boost::end(vec1), boost::begin(vec2), 0);
            })
        ];

    int attr = 0;
    if( x3::phrase_parse(boost::begin(input), boost::end(input), ruleSum >> x3::eoi, x3::ascii::space, attr) ) {
        std::cout<<"Match! result = "<<attr<<std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout<<"Not match!"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cdf2bc14c0fb0de)</kbd>**

Prints:

```
Match! result = 32
```